# can't get datas, from html file

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I'm a quite new user of GeoServer.

I've a created a layergroup, and it's work with the layer preview (OpenLayers).

But if I save the source as a .html to the directory of data dir/www, and open it I can see the layers, but can't get the feature data.

What do I wrong?

Comment: how are you opening the file? make sure it is through localhost not file://...

Comment: What do you mean by " save the source as a .html to the directory of data dir/www" ?

Comment: I thought if I open it to the /dir, I can get the feature data. I saved it, because I want to  modify with openlayers.